# switching from an input to button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to switch the button from `input` to `button` in Javascript and I cant figure out how to put value in between the `button` tag and the right syntax.How can I accomplish this ? Thanks

here is the  input button that I have

```
var somebutton = $("<input/>", { type: "button", value: "Save" });
```

i'd like something like this, but its not a right syntax

```
var somebutton = $("<button/>", { type: "button", {"Save"} });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `html` instead of `value`

```
var somebutton = $("<button/>", { type: "button", html: "Save" });
```